# validation contact form with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my code and i really don't know how to correct it. The validation works well but the problem is that when you fill in a name input field for example - dima, then you choose phone's field but the name's field is still doesn't have anything that you can see that you fill in it correctly, you have to select again this field and only than it adds some classes to the field. how can i fix this?

```
    <form name="myform>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="30">
          <p id="nameError">First name is required</p>
          <p id="nameErrorTwo">Enter only characters</p>
          <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
          <p id="telError">Phone is required</p>
          <p id="telErrorTwo">Enter a number</p>                
    </form>

 // firstname
    document.myform.firstname.onblur= function() {
        var name = document.myform.firstname.value;
        if (name === "") {
            document.myform.firstname.removeAttribute("class", "ready");
            document.myform.firstname.style.border = "1px solid #da3637";
            document.getElementById("nameError").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("nameErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            //firstname onchange
            document.myform.firstname.onchange= function() {
                document.myform.firstname.style.border = "1px solid #509d12";
                document.getElementById("nameError").style.display = "none";
                document.myform.firstname.setAttribute("class", "ready");
                var pattern = new RegExp("\[a-z]+", "i");
                var isValid = this.value.search(pattern) >= 0;

                if (!(isValid)) {
                    document.myform.firstname.style.border = "1px solid #da3637";
                    document.getElementById("nameErrorTwo").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("nameErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
                    document.myform.firstname.style.border = "1px solid #509d12";
                }
            };
        }
    };

//phone
    document.myform.phone.onblur= function() {
        var name = document.myform.phone.value;
        if (name === "") {
            document.myform.phone.removeAttribute("class", "ready");
            document.myform.phone.style.border = "1px solid #da3637";
            document.getElementById("telError").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("telErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            //phone onchange
            document.myform.phone.onchange= function() {
                document.myform.phone.style.border = "1px solid #509d12";
                document.getElementById("telError").style.display = "none";
                document.myform.phone.setAttribute("class", "ready");
                var pattern = new RegExp("\\d", "i");
                var isValid = this.value.search(pattern) >= 0;

                if (!(isValid)) {
                    document.myform.phone.style.border = "1px solid #da3637";
                    document.getElementById("telErrorTwo").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("telErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
                    document.myform.phone.style.border = "1px solid #509d12";
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead to use onchange you may use oninput to control char after char, or onblur to make the test when you will lose the focus.

```js
function setFieldValidity(element, pattern) {
  var isValid = element.value === '' || element.value.search(pattern) >= 0;
  if (!isValid) {
    element.removeAttribute("class", "ready");
    element.style.border = "1px solid #da3637";
    document.getElementById("nameError").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("nameErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    element.setAttribute("class", "ready");
    element.style.border = "1px solid #509d12";
    document.getElementById("nameError").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("nameErrorTwo").style.display = "block";
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  //firstname
  document.myform.firstname.oninput  = function(e) {
    setFieldValidity(this,  new RegExp("\[a-z]+$", "i"));
  };

  //phone
  document.myform.phone.oninput  = function(e) {
    setFieldValidity(this,  new RegExp("^\\d+$", "i"));
  };
}, false);
```

```html
<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="30">
    <p id="nameError">First name is required</p>
    <p id="nameErrorTwo">Enter only characters</p>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <p id="telError">Phone is required</p>
    <p id="telErrorTwo">Enter a number</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, the `onchange()` event listeners are set up only when the fields lose focus with a non-empty value. This explains the weird behaviors that you're encountering.

Actually, I don't see any reason to use a mix of `onblur()` and `onchange()`.

Please see if the following version is doing what you're expecting. It's using `onchange()` exclusively.

```js
// firstname
    document.myform.firstname.onchange= function() {
        var name = document.myform.firstname.value;
        if (name === "") {
            document.myform.firstname.removeAttribute("class", "ready");
            document.myform.firstname.style.border = "1px solid #da3637";
            document.getElementById("nameError").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("nameErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("nameError").style.display = "none";
            document.myform.firstname.setAttribute("class", "ready");
            var pattern = new RegExp("^[a-z]+$", "i");
            var isValid = this.value.search(pattern) >= 0;

            if (!(isValid)) {
                document.myform.firstname.style.border = "1px solid #da3637";
                document.getElementById("nameErrorTwo").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("nameErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
                document.myform.firstname.style.border = "1px solid #509d12";
            }
        }
    };

//phone
    document.myform.phone.onchange= function() {
        var name = document.myform.phone.value;
        if (name === "") {
            document.myform.phone.removeAttribute("class", "ready");
            document.myform.phone.style.border = "1px solid #da3637";
            document.getElementById("telError").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("telErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            //phone onchange
            document.getElementById("telError").style.display = "none";
            document.myform.phone.setAttribute("class", "ready");
            var pattern = new RegExp("^\\d+$");
            var isValid = this.value.search(pattern) >= 0;

            if (!(isValid)) {
                document.myform.phone.style.border = "1px solid #da3637";
                document.getElementById("telErrorTwo").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("telErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
                document.myform.phone.style.border = "1px solid #509d12";
            }
        }
    };
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="30">
    <p id="nameError">First name is required</p>
    <p id="nameErrorTwo">Enter only characters</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <p id="telError">Phone is required</p>
    <p id="telErrorTwo">Enter a number</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Arnauld thanks a lot, now it works how it's supposed to do :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Aside: your original regular expressions were testing whether the name contains _at least one letter_ and whether the phone contains _at least one digit_. I don't think that's the expected behavior (see my edited answer for a fix).

Comment: yes i know that my validation isn't perfect, my thanks to you, now it works great